# Is there R function to extract number amounts from string of Chinese characters?

Tags: r, dplyr, nlp, cjk

I have a string like `d`

```
d <- c("您尾号1234卡11月11日00:03转入人民币1,500.00元，余额人民币1,501.12元",
       "您尾号3256卡11月11日00:03转出人民币678.12元，余额人民币1,501.12元",
       "您尾号7894卡11月11日00:03取现0.85元，余额人民币1,501.12元",
       "您尾号3285卡11月11日00:03支付3.85元，余额人民币1,501.12元")
```

The string is an activity log of money payments through a bank credit.
I want to extract the payment amount money. For example:
I want to extract "1,500.00" "678.12" "0.85" "3.85". Additionally, how can I convert the values to to numeric?

Comment: What about the second numerical values in each string e.g. `1,501.12` in the first string?  Do you not want to extract those?

Comment: Yes I want to extract them too

Comment: The pinyin character for 'yuan' is '元', so it's trivially easy to write a regex to capture the decimal amount preceding the '元'. You don't even need to understand any Chinese to do that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `str_extract` function from `stringr`.

The positive lookahead `(?=)` looks for the `元` symbol.

The negative lookbehind `(?!<)` insures that the balance value is not captured.

Then we can use `str_replace_all` to remove the commas.

Finally, we can convert to numeric.

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(d,"(?!<余额人民币)[0-9.,]+(?=元)") %>%
   str_replace_all(",","") %>%
   as.numeric()
[1] 1500.00  678.12    0.85    3.85
```

If you want to capture all of the numbers, you can use `str_extract_all` and omit the negative lookbehind.

```
library(purrr)
str_extract_all(d,"[0-9.,]+(?=元)") %>% 
   map(~str_replace_all(.,",","") %>% as.numeric)
[[1]]
[1] 1500.00 1501.12

[[2]]
[1]  678.12 1501.12

[[3]]
[1]    0.85 1501.12

[[4]]
[1]    3.85 1501.12
```

Comment: I want to extract ""1,500.00"
Your answer only extract "500.00"

Answer (score 2):

here are two options with the rebus, readr and stringr/stringi package:

```
library(rebus)
library(readr)
library(stringr)
library(stringi)

pattern <- optional(one_or_more(DGT) %R% ",") %R% optional(one_or_more(DGT) %R% ",") %R% one_or_more(DGT) %R% DOT %R% one_or_more(DGT)

d <- c("您尾号1234卡11月11日00:03转入人民币1,500.00元，余额人民币1,501.12元", "您尾号3256卡11月11日00:03转出人民币678.12元，余额人民币1,501.12元", "您尾号7894卡11月11日00:03取现0.85元，余额人民币1,501.12元", "您尾号3285卡11月11日00:03支付3.85元，余额人民币1,501.12元")

readr::parse_number(stringr::str_extract(d, pattern))

[1] 1500.00  678.12    0.85    3.85

readr::parse_number(unique(unlist(stringi::stri_extract_all_regex(d,pattern))))

[1] 1500.00 1501.12  678.12    0.85    3.85
```

Answer (score 1):

there is a python library which could solve this question

## JioNLP

- installation

```
$ pip install jionlp
```

- extract money
  [Extract money](https://github.com/dongrixinyu/JioNLP/wiki/%E6%AD%A3%E5%88%99%E6%8A%BD%E5%8F%96%E4%B8%8E%E8%A7%A3%E6%9E%90-%E8%AF%B4%E6%98%8E%E6%96%87%E6%A1%A3#user-content-%E6%8A%BD%E5%8F%96%E9%87%91%E9%A2%9D%E5%AD%97%E7%AC%A6%E4%B8%B2)

```
import jionlp as jio
text = ["您尾号1234卡11月11日00:03转入人民币1,500.00元，余额人民币1,501.12元",
        "您尾号3256卡11月11日00:03转出人民币678.12元，余额人民币1,501.12元",
        "您尾号7894卡11月11日00:03取现0.85元，余额人民币1,501.12元",
        "您尾号3285卡11月11日00:03支付3.85元，余额人民币1,501.12元"]

for i in text:
    res = jio.extract_money(i)
    print(res)
```

and you will get the result:

```
['1,500.00元', '1,501.12元']
['678.12元', '1,501.12元']
['0.85元', '1,501.12元']
['3.85元', '1,501.12元']
```

please star this github project.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R solution:

```r
txt <- "您尾号1234卡11月11日00:03转入人民币1,500.00元，余额人民币1,501.12元"
regmatches(txt,gregexpr("\\d{1,3}(?:,\\d{3})*\\.\\d{2}", txt))[[1]]

[1] "1,500.00" "1,501.12"
```

The regex used above says to match:

```
\d{1,3}       a leading 1 to 3 digits
(?:,\\d{3})*  followed by zero or more thousands separator 3 digit groups
\\.\\d{2}     followed by a decimal component with 2 digits of precision
```

Note that I assume that the matches you want have two decimal places.  Otherwise, it would be harder to discern what be a currency amount.  We would need some other context in that case.

Answer (score 0):

I have added 2.1M, again assuming decimals are the target

```
d <- c("您尾号1234卡11月11日00:03转入人民币2,100,500.00元，余额人民币1,501.12元",
       "您尾号3256卡11月11日00:03转出人民币678.12元，余额人民币1,501.12元",
       "您尾号7894卡11月11日00:03取现0.85元，余额人民币1,501.12元",
       "您尾号3285卡11月11日00:03支付3.85元，余额人民币1,501.12元")


str_extract_all(d,"(\\d+,?)*\\.\\d+")
```